# Can I create Buttons with a Function in Python?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

**My Goal:**
I want to be able to program buttons for a calculator which output their corresponding number easily, by using a function.

**What I have tried:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def Buttons(num,x,y):
    global int
    int = num
    but1 = Button(root, padx=50, pady=50, text=num, command=Click)
    but1.grid(row=y, column=x)

def Click():
    but = Label(root, text=int)
    but.grid(row=4, column=0)


Buttons(7,0,0)
Buttons(8,1,0)
Buttons(9,2,0)
Buttons(4,0,1)
Buttons(5,1,1)
Buttons(6,2,1)
Buttons(1,0,2)
Buttons(2,1,2)
Buttons(3,2,2)
Buttons(0,1,3)

root.mainloop()
```

**The Problem**
The output is always int from the last used Buttons function. (in this case the output will always be "0" no matter which of the buttons I press.)
I know that it does that because I set int to be global. What do I have to do so that the button outputs its corresponding number?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to go about this, here's one of my approaches

```py
def Buttons(num,x,y):
    but1 = Button(root, padx=50, pady=50, text=num, command=lambda:Click(num))
    but1.grid(row=y, column=x)

def Click(int):
    but = Label(root, text=int)
    but.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

**NOTES**

- You can make use of the `lamda` function and set the commands of these buttons to call the `click` function along with the number it represents as the parameter, the variable `num` in this case.
- Instead of using `grid` to put a new lable every time, you might also want to make use of the `but.config(text=str(int))` or `but['text']=str(int)` to change the values after having the label *gridded* once in the main code.